# Show list of roles in a dropdown box but leave out "Admin" role

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a dropdown box showing a list of roles. I used Roles.GetAllroles() for showing all roles in the dropdown box but I don't want to show a role named "Admin" in the dropdown box. How can I keep it out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(1) After you create the `Selectlist` in the controller removed the Admin `ListItem`

```
SelectList sl =  new SelectList(Roles.GetAllRoles(), "roleName")
//remove items as needed
ViewData["roleName"] = sl;
```

Or (2) step through the `GetAllroles()` collection and don't add the role if it is the Admin role.

Comment: thanx, i am using mvc 1.0 so my code is 

<%= Html.DropDownList("roleName") %> and conrtoller code is
ViewData["roleName"] = new SelectList(Roles.GetAllRoles(), "roleName");

can u please tell how to do step 1 ?

Answer (score 1):

Try creating an extension method on the provider type and wrap the call. This will allow you to add additional criteria later if needed.

```
public static class RolesExtension
{
    public static string[] GetAllNonAdminRoles(this RoleProvider providerInstance)
    {
        return (from role in providerInstance.GetAllRoles()
                where !role.Equals("Admin", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                select role).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Instead of ...

```
System.Web.Security.Roles.GetAllRoles();
```

Call this ...

```
System.Web.Security.Roles.Provider.GetAllNonAdminRoles();
```